# how to cast string data type to decimal and int from data table to sql table

Tags: c#, sql

I am inserting values to SQL table from a data table and i am getting "converting data type errors". My source file is fixed width and i am using substring to get these values.

```
Source:

    Amount       Name       Id            Date
    -33,167.74   NHP       1,503         05/09/2017
```

This is my code to insert SQL table using data table

```
private DataTable InsertDataTable()
{
    DataTable datatable = new DataTable();
    datatable.Columns.Add("Id", typeof(int));
    datatable.Columns.Add("amount", typeof(decimal));
    datatable.Columns.Add("name", typeof(string));
    datatable.Columns.Add("date", typeof(datetime));

    //--inserting datatable

    foreach (string row in columns)
    {
        datarow["Id"] = Convert.ToInt32(row.Substring(51, 12).Trim().Replace(",", ""));
        datarow["Amount"] = Convert.ToDecimal(row.Substring(0, 9).Trim());
        datarow["date"] = Convert.ToDateTime(row.Substring(12, 18).Trim());
        datarow["name"] = Convert.ToDecimal(row.Substring(20, 35).Trim());
        datatable.Rows.Add(datarow);
    }
}

private void InsertSqlTable()
{
    DataTable finaldatatable = InsertDataTable();
    //sql connection--------------------
    using (SqlBulkCopy sqlBulkCopy = new SqlBulkCopy(con))
    {
        //Set the database table name
        sqlBulkCopy.DestinationTableName = "[dbo].[table]";
        sqlBulkCopy.ColumnMappings.Add("id", "id");
        sqlBulkCopy.ColumnMappings.Add("amount", "amount");
        sqlBulkCopy.ColumnMappings.Add("name", "name");
        sqlBulkCopy.ColumnMappings.Add("date", "date");
    }
}
```

My target table has below columns and data types

```
id int
name string
amount money
date  datetime
```

I am getting conversion errors for all the data types except string. also my Id is 1,503 and I want 1503. 
Can anyone of you help me converting to correct datatype and also eliminating comma from ID ?
any help is appreciated!

Comment: If I am counting correctly, amount has 10 characters from position 0, right? These substring positions are all off are they not?

Comment: since this is mocked up data, my substring values differ. Firstly I want to know how to remove comma from any value in data table.

Comment: Can't help you with the C#, someone else will need to guide you there. But this does not change the fact that "-33,167.74" contains 10 characters and your substring only has a length of 9.

Comment: Is .Replace(",","") not working to get rid of the commas before ever inserting into the datatable?

Comment: yes. i did that and can convert for int. but stuck for decimal(money). -33,167.74 should be money in sql and error is, input string not in correct format.

Answer (score 0):

You can get your desire output by using `Regex`. I've considered that all of your data will formatted like the example data.

Firstly I've used `Regex` to get `Id, Amount & date`, after that I get `name`.

Regex:

```
((-|)\b\d[\d,.\/]*\b)
```

[Regex101 Example](https://regex101.com/r/qYNMws/1/).

Example C# Code:

```
using System;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        string data = "-33,167.74   NHP       1,503         05/09/2017";

        string regex = @"((-|)\b\d[\d,.\/]*\b)";
        var matches = Regex.Matches(data, regex, RegexOptions.Multiline);

        int Id = Convert.ToInt16(matches[1].Groups[0].ToString().Replace(",", ""));
        decimal Amount = Convert.ToDecimal(matches[0].Groups[0].ToString());
        DateTime date = Convert.ToDateTime(matches[2].Groups[0].ToString());
        string name = Regex.Replace(data, regex, "").ToString().Trim();

        Console.WriteLine("Id: " + Id);
        Console.WriteLine("Amount: " + Amount);
        Console.WriteLine("date: " + date);
        Console.WriteLine("name: " + name);
    }
}
```

[Output of example in DotNetFiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/MQGQfK).

Please change below statements in your code:

```
foreach (string row in columns)
{
    string data = row;

    string regex = @"((-|)\b\d[\d,.\/]*\b)";
    var matches = Regex.Matches(data, regex, RegexOptions.Multiline);

    int Id = Convert.ToInt16(matches[1].Groups[0].ToString().Replace(",", ""));
    decimal Amount = Convert.ToDecimal(matches[0].Groups[0].ToString());
    DateTime date = Convert.ToDateTime(matches[2].Groups[0].ToString());
    string name = Regex.Replace(data, regex, "").ToString().Trim();

    datarow["Id"] = Id;
    datarow["Amount"] = Amount;
    datarow["date"] = date;
    datarow["name"] = name;
    datatable.Rows.Add(datarow);
}
```